# how do I exclude child categories from a wp_query?

Tags: wp-query

I'm doing a category-based search that looks like this:

```
$feed = WP_Query("category_name=noticias&showposts=3&order=DESC");
```

The problem is this also brings me posts from the child categories, which I would like to avoid... how do I do this?

If I do something like

```
$feed = query_posts(array('category__in' => array(102)));
```

Then I am told that $feed is not an object next time I try to do something with it... that's why WP_Query was good for me in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `'category__in'` in WP_Query; 
example:

```
$feed = WP_Query(array('category__in' => array(102), 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'order' => 'DESC'));
```